# Hi! So I just deleted a node on Kubernetes. Since nodes are internally created, is there anyway to restore it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I just deleted a node on Kubernetes Google Cloud. Since nodes are internally created, is there anyway to restore it?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, Kubernetes should take care of recreating the nodes.  In the particular case of GKE that task is assigned to the [instance managed group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/).

Since all the logic is managed by Kubernetes, there is not a function that will allow you to recreate a specific node. Instead you have features that will allow you to [resize your cluster](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/resize-cluster) or change how [node pools are configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455020/gke-adding-nodes-to-a-cluster-that-are-of-different-sizes).